# How to get around not being able to INSERT or DELETE in a function

Tags: sql-server, function, insert

I have an issue where I can't see a good way to get around INSERTING and DELETING inside a function. My issue is that I have a CLR function that I call inside my SQL function, that needs to pull data from an intermediary table (as I can't call this function with a type table variable as I would've liked) and as such I need to prepare the data that the CLR function uses first in these intermediary tables. I think the below snippet shows what I'm trying to do:

```
    DELETE FROM MATRIX.LinearEquationSolverIntermediaryMatrixA
    DELETE FROM MATRIX.LinearEquationSolverIntermediaryMatrixB

    INSERT INTO MATRIX.LinearEquationSolverIntermediaryMatrixA  ---Intermediary Table to hold values for CLR function. Purge table after use
            ( i, j, value )
    SELECT  i , j ,value FROM @A
    INSERT INTO MATRIX.LinearEquationSolverIntermediaryMatrixB  ---Intermediary Table to hold values for CLR function. Purge table after use
            ( i, j, value )
    SELECT  i , j ,value FROM @B

    INSERT INTO @c_
    SELECT value, idx FROM [dbo].[f_SolveLinearEquation]()  ---CLR Function to solve linear equation very fast.

    DELETE FROM MATRIX.LinearEquationSolverIntermediaryMatrixA
    DELETE FROM MATRIX.LinearEquationSolverIntermediaryMatrixB
```

Is there a way to do something like this inside a function? If there's a different way to approach the CLR function that I'm not considering that is of course also something I could look at

Comment: Start at the beginning: why do you need a CLR function in the first place? And if you do, perhaps you actually need a CLR aggregate instead. We have no context here, we don't know what you are actually trying to do. We don't even have the full code for your UDF.

Comment: Hi, sorry okay. So I'm doing some linear algebra in SQL and need a way to solve a system of linear equations, so to that end I've created a CLR function that simple solves a system of linear equations with the MathNetNumerics nuget package. Intuitively I would of course just want to call this function with SolveLinearEquation(A,B) where A and B are my matrices, but since CLR functions don't allow that I have this other solution where insert the data into tables that the CLR function then uses.

The UDF simple creates the matrices @A and @B, and then uses my CLR function to solve the system.

Comment: Sounds like you actuallly want a CLR aggregate, which will accept the full table and spit out a single result

Comment: I see, so this user created aggregate function would be used in a select query then simple selecting from @A and @B? But can the aggregate function handle inputs from several column? In my case I would need to input not only the values in the matrices but the coordinates

Comment: I think you can just have multiple parameters on the `Accumulate`. Barring that, you'd have to either concat the values together into `varbinary` like this `cast(x as binary(4)) + cast(y as binary(4))` then you get it as a `byte[]` array in C#. Or you can define a User Defined Type which contains all of the values, and have a UDF that creates the type per row, which you then pass to the aggregate.

Comment: Thank you, I looked it up a bit and I think you’re right in that this is the way to go so I will try to rewrite my function as an aggregate, Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively, stored procedures are allowed to write to the database.

Comment: @Charlieface I started to make a CLR aggregate but I think this doesn't work still... The aggregate can only return 1 value where as my problem requires multiple outputs (a system of linear equations has several variables that each gets solved for a value). Do you have any suggestions? Perhaps I could return it as a single field in my CLR aggregate and then expand it into several values again in SQL like you were hinting at earlier (but other way around), not sure how I would do this in practice though.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, either as a `varbinary` or as a UDT. Your other option is to scrap all this, just pull all the data into a client app and bulk insert the results, but you can't do that in a function